# Combine mysql query result

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for words that contain "un" from two columns in a database table.
How can I get both row data in the output $data?

Example:

```
col1 | col2


tom -------- unfriendly

train ------- fast

unused--- cloth
```

.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%un%' 
OR col2 LIKE '%un%' 
ORDER BY col1 ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = $row['col1'];
}
```

I get $data = [tom,unused] from the above code.
How can I get $data = [ tom - friendly, unused - cloth] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1, ' - ', col2) AS result
FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%un%' OR
      col2 LIKE '%un%' 
ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

And then you would access the result set in your PHP code via:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = $row['result'];
}
```

Comment: reputation too low.. in the future

Answer (score 1):

As @TimBegeleisen said, you can use `CONCAT` in your SQL request, but you could also concat your string in your PHP code :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%un%' 
OR col2 LIKE '%un%' 
ORDER BY col1 ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = $row['col1'] . ' - ' . $data['col2'];
}
```

Comment: your answer works too but it came later and contains a typo.

Comment: Damn you typo !

Comment: Upvoted as a nice alternative.  It would be interesting to see which of the two methods would actually run faster on large data sets.